# Wordpress. Не работают русскоязычные метки. Где их настраивать?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 5.3.2–ru_RU. В сайдбаре стоит виджет "Облако меток". Для записей установлены метки, типа "Label1, Метка1". Если нажать на англоязычную метку, то Вордпресс показывает записи с ней, всё ок. Но если нажать на русскоязычную, то появляется вордпрессовская страница 404. В консоле браузера видно, что он не может найти страницу "https://xxxxxxxxx.org/tag/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b01" (в адресной строке стоит "[https://xxxxxxxxx.org/tag/Метка1](https://xxxxxxxxx.org/tag/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B01)").

Подскажите пожалуйста, где это настраивается?

Comment: Правильно настраивается сервер, а не ВП.

Comment: А где именно, не подскажете? Или, как правильно называется эта настройка, чтобы я смог загуглить?

Comment: Кодировка везде должна быть utf8